# Java code scrolls weirdly with nested scrollbar

Tags: bug, code-formatting, design

When I view https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399074/253468 in latest Chrome the first source code block scrolls normally until it reaches the `ToggleGroup` constructor (first method in `class ToggleGroup` where it starts another nested scrollable code block.

I checked the code and it's not markdown, it's `<pre><code>` and there're some HTML tags in the JavaDoc.

Comment: This appears to have been caused solely by the presence of the additional spaces in front of the `<pre><code>` that started the code block. Removing them seems to make it display properly (not insert another code block inside the already existing code block). At least it does in the live preview I was playing with below. Looks like the parser only notices it if it's at the very beginning of a new line.